# Complex arithmetics in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I frequently use complex arithmetics in CUDA and need to define my own implementations of, for example, transcendental functions (`sin`, `cos`, `exp`, ...) on complex numbers. I want now to definitely solve the problem by writing a library of such functions so to consider a "large" number of cases and avoiding being pit-stopped any time for new implementations.

I'm aware that for some of them, code writing could be non-trivial from the point of view of trade-off between accuracy and computational complexity. Nevertheless, I'm also aware that C++ has its own [complex math library](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_e/doc/ComplexArithmetic.pdf).

Is there any possibility to "recycle" already existing C++ solutions for CUDA purposes?

Comment: We have shared a library of `__device__` functions and operators on complex numbers at [CUDA Complex Library Download Page](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/bluebird) including the following functions: `real`, `imag`, `abs`, `angle`, `conj`, `log`, `log10`, `polar`, `sqrt`, `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, `exp`, `pow`, `asinh`, `acosh`, `atanh`, `sinh`, `cosh`, `tanh`, `asin`, `atan`, `acos`. In the downloadable compressed file, there is a Stand-Along Complex directory as well as a Visual Studio usage example. We hope it could be useful to the community. Of course, any criticism will be welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you already found the answer, but here is mine:

There is possibility to "recycle" [sources for complex C++ ISO library](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00813.html)

UPD:

CUDA related: [cusp::complex< float > Struct Template Reference](http://docs.cusp-library.googlecode.com/hg/structcusp_1_1complex_3_01float_01_4.html)

I think you can try to collaborate with the author of:

[an implementation of C++ std::complex for CUDA devices (i.e. compiles with nvcc)](https://github.com/jtravs/cuda_complex)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From a _fast_ look at the library you indicated, I would not be sure as the [implementation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00813_source.html) seems to rely on builtin functions...

Comment: Built-in where? In CPU/GPU?
Can you give an example on which built-in functions you want to rely on?

Comment: Look at this [source file](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00813_source.html#l00258). The definition of `asin` relies on a `__builtin_casinf` function. Opposite to this, I want to rely on CUDA built-in functions on real argument and extend them to the complex case.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I have submitted a "request for enhancement" to NVIDIA. I think that your second link is very useful and is almost exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much. +1 and accepted answer.