# how to get cufftcomplex magnitude and phase fast

Tags: cuda, fft

i have a cufftcomplex data block which is the result from cuda fft(R2C). i know the data is save as a structure with a real number followed by image number. now i want to get the amplitude=sqrt(R*R+I*I), and phase=arctan(I/R)   of each complex element by a fast way(not for loop). Is there any good way to do that? or any library could do that?

Comment: This isn't a very clearly written question. What do you mean by "I have a cofftcomplex|sic] block data"? Does that mean that you have a kernel which has block scope some data in shared memory and you want a device function for calculating the phase and magnitude? Or something else?

Comment: sorry for confusing. it is a cufftcomplex data block in device memory which is the results of cuda fft(R2C). I want to calculate the phase and magnitude.

Answer (score 4):

Since `cufftExecR2C` operates on data that is on the GPU, the results are already on the GPU, (before you copy them back to the host, if you are doing that.)

It should be straightforward to write your own cuda kernel to accomplish this.  The amplitude you're describing is the value returned by `cuCabs` or `cuCabsf` in `cuComplex.h` header file.  By looking at the functions in that header file, you should be able to figure out how to write your own that computes the phase angle. You'll note that `cufftComplex` is [just a typedef of](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#cufftcomplex) `cuComplex`.

let's say your cufftExecR2C call left some results of type `cufftComplex` in array `data` of size `sz`.  Your kernel might look like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#define nTPB 256    // threads per block for kernel
#define sz 100000   // or whatever your output data size is from the FFT
...

__host__ __device__ float carg(const cuComplex& z) {return atan2(cuCimagf(z), cuCrealf(z));} // polar angle

__global__ void magphase(cufftComplex *data, float *mag, float *phase, int dsz){
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < dsz){
    mag[idx]   = cuCabsf(data[idx]);
    phase[idx] = carg(data[idx]);
  }
}

...
int main(){
...
    /* Use the CUFFT plan to transform the signal in place. */
    /* Your code might be something like this already:      */
    if (cufftExecR2C(plan, (cufftReal*)data, data) != CUFFT_SUCCESS){
      fprintf(stderr, "CUFFT error: ExecR2C Forward failed");
      return;   
    }
    /* then you might add:                                  */
    float *h_mag, *h_phase, *d_mag, *d_phase;
    // malloc your h_ arrays using host malloc first, then...
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_mag, sz*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_phase, sz*sizeof(float));
    magphase<<<(sz+nTPB-1)/nTPB, nTPB>>>(data, d_mag, d_phase, sz);
    cudaMemcpy(h_mag, d_mag, sz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(h_phase, d_phase, sz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

You can also do this using [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) by creating functors for the magnitude and phase functions, and passing these functors along with `data`, `mag` and `phase` to [thrust::transform](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations.html#gacbd546527729f24f27dc44e34a5b8f73).

I'm sure you can probably do it with [CUBLAS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html) as well, using a combination of vector add and vector multiply operations.

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455414/how-to-do-power-of-complex-number-in-cublas/18455757#18455757) may be of interest as well.  I lifted my phase function `carg` from there.

Comment: Just a curiosity. The Fourier transform of a real function is Hermitian. To exploit such a simmetry, `cufftExecR2C` function stores only the nonredundant Fourier transform in the output array. Should you account for that in your kernel launch size `sz`?

Comment: Probably.  Is it not accounted for?  Nowhere did I specify the details of the cufft plan, which would identify the relationship between input and output sizes of the FFT.  I simply said it "left results of size `sz` in `data`".  How would you word it?  Should I delete the `#define sz` line to make it clearer?  Feel free to edit my answer.