# How to do the modulus of complex number more efficiently in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda

I was trying to do the Fast Fourier Transform to the data I collected. After the FFT operation, I wanted to calculate the modulus of the cufftComplex type data. Therefore, I summed the real part square and imaginary part square, and then took the square root of the summation. The code are provided below also the assignment of the grids and blocks:

```
dim3 dimBlock(256);
dim3 dimGrid(FFTlength / 256 * lines);

__global__ void modulus_kernel(int length, int lines, cufftComplex *PostFFTData, float* z) 
{
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(x<length*lines)
        z1[x] = sqrt(PostFFTData[x].x *PostFFTData[x].x + PostFFTData[x].y *PostFFTData[x].y);
    __syncthreads();
}
```

The length of the PostFFData pointer array is 1024000, and the length and lines are 2048 and 500 respectively. 
After I executed the code, I analyzed the timeline of the program by Nvidia Visual Profiler.
It shows that the modulus kernel took 0.367 ms to complete. Besides, the GPU card I used is GTX1080 and the CPU is i7-7700U. If I want to shorten the execution time, how should I do it?

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant in 2020 due to the fast changes CUDA goes trhouhg, but worth a shot/read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502087/how-to-get-cufftcomplex-magnitude-and-phase-fast

Comment: I tried the function `cuCabsf`, but the performance wasn't better. It required more tome to complete this step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I want to shorten the execution time, how should I do it?

I can think of at least five things (in no particular order)

1. Get rid of the `__syncthreads()` call. It is unnecessary and will actively slow down your code
2. Pass the kernel `length*lines` as a single argument to the kernel. Why have an *every thread* do an integer multiply for a value which is constant?
3. Use a [grid stride loop](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) and launch only as many threads as can be resident on the device. Use the [occupancy APIs](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-occupancy-api-simplifies-launch-configuration/) to let the runtime do the hard thinking about the launch parameters for you.
4. If the problem size allows  use `#pragma unroll` with a suggested unrolling length to hint to the compiler that the gride size loop can be partially unrolled. If that doesn't allow the compiler to generate a stream of floating point operations, then partially unroll the grid sized loop yourself.
5. Because you are passing single precision floating point values, use `sqrtf`, not `sqrt`. There are significant performance differences between double and single precision functions. If your application allows it, consider using less accurate versions of the sqrt function (`prec-sqrt=false`)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am not sure I understand about the third one and the fourth one. For the third one, The grid size I assigned is (4000,1,1) and the block size is (256,1,1). Does it means I should assign the grids and blocks smaller? For the fourth one, if it means I can follow the code in this article [unroll](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/new-compiler-features-cuda-8/).

Answer (score 1):

`__syncthreads();`

is useless since there is no sharing between threads

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, and it seemed like the time cost became short around 0.01 ms.